# resize middle div to fill space between divs when overflow:hidden; doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I've got four divs. one container and three columns. Column 1 and 3 has a fixed width, and column two needs to fill the gab between them. I would like the design to be re-sizable depending on the screen width, to a minimum of `300px`.

My HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="1"></div>
    <div id="2"></div>
    <div id="3"></div>
</div>
```

the CSS

```
#container {
width:100%;
min-width:300px;
position:relative;
}
#1 {
float:left;
min-width:300px;
min-height:10px;
background-color:red;
}

#2 {
overflow:hidden;
width:100%;
min-height:10px;
background-color:blue;
}

#3 {
float:right;
min-width:300px;
background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove width: 100%; from #2. It will automaticly take whole free space.
Check fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ozeczek/aVbC6/

Comment: what browser do you use, because for me it looks like the blue is going over the green at the end. And the green is not 300px wide.

Comment: default newest chrome

Comment: u;re right, something is wrong with green, wait a sec, sorry!

Comment: check it now, You just need to switch right div with center. http://fiddle.jshell.net/ozeczek/aVbC6/

Comment: or if you dont want to use overflow: hidden, and you know width of left and right div you can use margin values: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ozeczek/qk5pV/4/